# How do i pass a number from a list as a parameter in scheme?

Tags: list, parameters, scheme

I need to take a number from a list and convert it to a number so that i can pass it as a parameter.

im trying to make a 1-bit adder in scheme. i've written the code for the or gate and the xor gate and also the half adder and now im trying to combine them all to make a full adder. im not sure if im going about it the right way. any input will be appreciated thank you.

```
(define or-gate
 (lambda (a b)
  (if (= a 1)
    1
    (if (= b 1)
    1
    0))))
(define xor-gate
 (lambda (a b)
  (if (= a b)
    0
    1)))

(define ha
 (lambda (a b)
  (list (xor-gate a b)(and-gate a b))))

(define fa
 (lambda (a b cin)
  (or-gate (cdr(ha cin (car (ha a b))))(cdr(ha a b)))))
```

the issue i get when i run the program is that the half adder (ha) function outputs a list as a value and that makes the values incompatible with my other procedures because they require numbers and not lists. i feel like there is a simple solution but i dont know it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot easier reading your code if you had a contract; it took me quite a while to deduce that your half-adder was returning a list of bits.

Next, it looks to me like you're having a simple issue with "cdr". The "cdr" operator does not return the second element of a list, but the "rest" of the list. Check out the difference between (cdr (list 1 1)) and 1. The first produces a list containing 1, the second one produces the number 1.

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what you mean. the simple logic gates you can just pass in a 1 or 0 and for the half adder the you do the same but the output is supposed to be a list. this is a programming assignment for a class

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I misread your code. Let me revise my comment (somewhat). Hang on...

Comment: i changed all the conditions from (if (= a 1)) etc. to the equals? after doing this i now get an output but it is always zero no matter what the input it

Comment: Nope, this isn't what you want to do. Stick with =. The "equals?" is just covering up your real problem: the list containing 1 is not the same value as 1. You need a different way to refer to the second element of the list.

Comment: i used cdr because the list only contains 2 elements

Comment: Yes, but 'cdr' does *not* return the second element of a list.

Comment: i solved my parameter issue by using cadr i ended up with the full adder procedure looking like this... 
    (define fa
  (lambda (a b cin)
    (list (car(ha cin (car(ha a b ))))
     (or-gate (cadr(ha cin (car (ha a b)))) (cadr(ha a b))))))
the first value of the list is the sum and the second value is the carry-out. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding confusion, it's a good idea to use the procedures `first` and `second` instead of `car` and `cadr` for accessing the first and second elements of a list, respectively. Notice that `cdr` does *not* return the second element of a list, instead it returns the *rest* of a list, which is another list.

Anyway, the `fa` procedure in the question doesn't look right to me. It should be returning a list with both the `sum` and `cout` values. Here's one possible way to implement it, using `first` and `second` as suggested:

```
(define fa
  (lambda (a b cin)
    (list (first (ha a (first (ha b cin))))
          (or-gate (second (ha a (first (ha b cin))))
                   (second (ha b cin))))))
```

... But that looks confusing. Notice that we're calculating `(ha b cin)` in three parts, a better idea would be to save the repeated calculation in a variable, like this:

```
(define fa
  (lambda (a b cin)
    (let* ((partial1 (ha b cin))
           (partial2 (ha a (first partial1))))
      (list (first partial2)
            (or-gate (second partial2) (second partial1))))))
```

As a final note, in the book [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) there's a very nice implementation of adders as part of a simulator for digital circuits, take a [look](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%_sec_3.3.4) at it for further ideas on how to improve your code.